# Better way for autocomplete in Eclipse Neon

Tags: c++, eclipse, intellisense, shortcut

At the moment, I am looking for better way to use autocomplete or "content assist" in eclipse.
They suggest using Ctrl + Space. 
I hope they can bring something like intellisense in Visual Studio or Monodevelop.
I found one of page add trigger as all the possible key to content assist, but this is only for Java. And I using c++. They only have some option such as '.' '->' and '::'.
So for the moment, I just bind key '`' instead of Ctrl + Space.

Anyone have better idea please let me know. Currently I using 
Eclipse Neon IDE for C/C++ Developer
Version Neon.2 Release  4.6.2

Comment: Where should i ask this question?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/?